# Removing static member from a header

Tags: c++

What the difference between a static member variable of a class and a "free" variable defined in the "body" of the class? I mean can I use the second in place of the first to discharge a header of the class?

```
// b.h
class B
{
public:
  B(int j);
  void print();
private:
  static int is;
};


//b.cpp
#include <iostream>

int i = 0;
int B::is = 0;

B::B(int j)
{
  i = j;
  is = j;
}

void B::print(){
  std::cout << i << " " << is << " " << std::endl;
}

//main.cpp
int main() {
  B b1(1);
  b1.print();
  B b2(2);
  b2.print();
  b1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 1 
2 2 
2 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the difference is that the static member data can be accessed only by the class, as it is declared in the `private` section of the class, which may be desirable in some cases. The global `i` can be changed by anyone.

So if a variable is meant for the class only, and shouldn't be used by others, then having a static member data in the `private` section is a better solution. It gives you restricted access to the variable. Global variables are bad in general, as it gives unrestricted access to anyone.

Note that in your case, the global variable `i` has *external* linkage. In other files, one could simply declare as `extern int i`, and then can use `i` and *modify* it as well.

Even if you make it `static` global variable, to make it have *internal* linkage, it is not good as compared to `static` member data, because the static member data gives you some sort of idea that the variable is used by the class only, not by non-class members (if any in the same file). So `static` member data increases readability, in comparison to global `static` data.

Comment: it has file scope of b.cpp, who can change it and how?

Comment: @DmitryKachko: From the other files, the global variable can be used, as in your case it has `external` linkage. In other files, you can simple declare as `extern int i`, and then can use (and *modify*) the variable.

Comment: global variables are bad for the reason of namespaces clash, of course I can put it in a namespace and it is just simple example and it is not matter of the question.

Comment: The matter why I ask --  my class is using static variables that are not a part of its interface, they are just a kind of helpers, and a reader of the code doesn't care what helping variables are used by the class.

Comment: As another option, can I put it in anonymous namespace to make internal linkage?

Comment: variables in an unnamed namespaces have *external* linkage. But you can do that, as even though the variables has external linkage, no other file can access the variables from unnamed namespace defined in difference `.cpp` files. But as I said, it is still namespace level variables, and becomes unrelated to the class, even though the class is using the variable. If only the class is using it, then I would still say that `static` member is much better than defining them in an unnamed namespace.